# Hosting not loading pages

Tags: apache, apache2, hosting, web-hosting

i am new to web hosting, but i purchased a domain from namecheap.com and i purchased web hosting from ramnode.com to host my domain, i am using centOS 32bit as my server, and i have pointed my domain to ramnode nameservers that were provided to me.

The problem i am having here is that everytime i load my website, it just says

Index Of/

cgi-bin/

even though i have placed my web page files in var/www, and var/www/html like ramnode support told me too, it still does not want to work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on how your server is setup but here are a few things to check.

What are the permission levels for your files, who owns them and what group are they in?  If you don't have proper permissions set they may not show.  If the wrong person owns them they may not show.

Read over your httpd.conf (centos should have it in /etc/httpd/conf) see how your server is setup.  It may not have a default setup, perhaps your using a virtual host?

In a nutshell we need more information to help you out.

Comment: having my URL show Index Of/ indicates that my domain is communicating with my server correctly? If so, then i assume i have a httpd problem?  do i need to configure my <Virtualhost *:80>? because atm it is hashed out

Answer (score 0):

You should have an
 .htaccess or htaccess.txt file in your WWW root,  whithin that file you need the following line:

DirectoryIndex index.htm index.html index.php

That is the priority order of your index page.  (Your web project needs an index page)
So in otherwords your webserver will serve the first matching file that it finds in that list.

*A quick fix if you cant find the htaccess file,  is just make sure you have an index.html file in your var/www*

Answer (score 0):

I just reset my nameservers to point to ramnode's last night and am experiencing the same issue as the OP this morning.

I previously had no FQDN for the ramnode server and simply used my /etc/hosts file locally to point to the ramnode server. Through that method, I was able to make sure everything was setup just so - apache virtualhosts, .htaccess files, apache.conf, and httpd.conf files all operating as desired.

It seems to have something to do with the installation of the cpanel, which auto-fills DNS A records with a different IP than the one I was provided. changing it to ramnode's original IP simply leads to the same cgi-bin directory index. But going going to the original ip in the browser leads to my site, as I have the apache virtualhost set for the IP.

Ramnode sets subdomain a records such as cpanel.mydomain.com all set to the same new IP and those do function, so it leads me to believe a ramnode server is capturing the trafic elsewhere and should be sending it on but isn't.

It's a bit confusing where cpanel is taking me and why redirecting to my the domain.com. A record to the original IP seems to have no effect.